# How would I create a dynamical line graph chart with multiple line graphs?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, charts

I am trying to create a dynamical line graph chart with multiple line graphs on the chart.

For example, I want to be able to graph this data, where each PADD will be its own chart, and on each of these charts, the lines will consist of the different companies, the x-axis is the date, and the y-axis is the FSC%. Here is an example of the data:

[image]

I want the graphs to be able to automatically update as soon as new data comes in. I know I'll need my data to be in a table format and not in a range. Most videos online show people using "Recommended Charts", and they are able to find their chart that way, but whenever I do that, the results look absurd.

Any idea how I might be able to do this?

Comment: Start by rearranging the data so that each PADD is its own column and each date its own row, then generate a chart from that

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad, that worked, but now I'll have to restructure my query so a chart can be automatically formulated, which might be a hassel. But thank you for your help.